# Tableview is bouncing when reloadRows(at: [indexPath], with: .fade) is called from did select row at index path

Tags: ios, scroll, tableview, swift4, reloadrows

I am having this weird issue. when I scroll tableview and update some cell it bounce equivalent to the amount first cell scrolled.

I am having one view controller with tableview in it and based on user select some rows i'm updating only that row using below code

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    let index = indexPath.row
    print(index)
    let service = services[indexPath.row]
    if service.isEnabled {
        service.isEnabled = false
    }
    else {
        service.isEnabled = true
    }
    let indexPath = IndexPath(item: index, section: 0)
    serviceTableView.reloadRows(at: [indexPath], with: .fade)
}
```

this is working fine if I don't scroll the table view but if i scroll table view and select some cell its bounce the entire tableview

Things already tried

1. Removing all constraints of table view, it still bounce
2. Removing all config methods from cellForRowAt indexPath
3. Different simulators

also I am not doing anything in section view.

PS: What I observe is that it only happens when first cell is partially visible/hidden.

[image: gif image added for reference]

Comment: Why do you reload? What about changing the UI part on that method: `if let cell = tableView.cell(forIndexPath:indexPath) as MyCell{//changeUI}`?

Comment: func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "MusicServiceTableViewCell") as! MusicServiceTableViewCell
        cell.selectionStyle = .none
        cell.delegate = self
        let service = services[indexPath.row]
        cell.configureCell(withService: service, index: indexPath.row)
        return cell
    }

Comment: even if I comment all that code and just show static label still its behaving like this

Comment: And this is only happening in simulator I run the same code in device 10.3 iPhone 5 its working perfectly. So I'm thinking it must be some simulator issue

Comment: Have you implemented `estimatedHeightForRowAt`?

Comment: yes func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
        return 80
    }